# Can a bot take a parameter from website it is deployed on?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have developed a bot using C# and deployed it using direct line api.

I am trying to find a way for the bot to receive a parameter from the website when it initially loads.

I want the same bot to work on different websites and want the bot to recognize the website using this parameter sent by the website to the bot and then act according to that website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Backchannel** is probably what you are looking for. In the readme on [this repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) if you scroll to the last section you can read more about it.  It allows Webchat and the host can send/receive whatever you want from each other.

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for! Thanks a lot

Comment: I've deployed my bot using the backchannel and it works great. But it isnt supported by internet explorer. Is there a way to use the bot on internet explorer?

Comment: I do not know off the top of my head, but I think you should ask another question.  More people will see it if it's a question rather than a comment.